# Python 3.5 pip version conflict with python 2.7

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a software using pip install and my python and pip versions are 3.5. but when I run `sudo pip install -e .` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.5", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2675, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.14-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 552, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==8.1.0
```

Why Do I get an error with python 2.7 and please some one could sortout my issue.

Comment: You’re likely running a Python 2.7 pip. Try `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pip version and python versions are separate. It looks like your package requires exactly pip 8.1.0. You have to either upgrade/downgrade to that version first, or modify the software to work with whichever pip you have available.

Also, it may be easier to install the software in a virtual environment rather than system/global one. Changing the system version of pip may break either current apps, or the future pip package updates.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am running on a virtual environment on a csh(not sure mentioning this would help.). It seems I need to upgrade the existing version but unfortunately when I run sudo pip3.5 install --upgrade pip "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==8.1.0" pops up. It seems I need pip 8.1 to update pip 7.0.3. This cant be true. you have any suggestions.

Comment: If you use `sudo`, you're most likely going out of the virtualenv. (unless you specifically configured it differently) Either do it all as a normal user, or if your virtualenv is owned by root them specify full path to the `pip3.5` you want (otherwise you'll use the system one)